# Grease pencil viewport problem

Tags: grease-pencil

I have a problem with the visualisation of a grease pencil stroke.. I create a simple stoke and it appears green instead of black ( and it's the same for all the colors ). When I move in the viewport, it looks glitchy.. I take some screenshots :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgKlD.jpg

The 2st and the 3st is the zoomed version .

I have a 2019 macbook pro, with a 2,6 GHz Intel Core i7 and the graphic card Radeon Pro 560X 4 Go, Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 Mo.

I also have a video of the problem : I also have a video of the problem :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/55aqJ.jpg

Can Someone help me please ?

Comment: Have you checked here to see if you find a solution? https://www.blender.org/features/grease-pencil/

Comment: @Luciano Yes, unfortunately I didn't find any answer

Comment: that looks very strange, I can't reproduce the problem on my iMac.

Comment: @Luciano I also have an Imac, and it's perfectly normal.. On my macbook pro, at the beginning it was fine, but one day it suddenly became glitchy.. And I don't know what is the cause.. I donwloaded Blender 2.81 and 2.82 and it's the same result..

Comment: [I'm getting the same thing](https://imgur.com/bnR4yy7)... Retina 5K iMac, Late 2014. AMD Radeon RM9 4GB video card.

Comment: I go back from Osx Catalina to Mojave and it works perfectly now.. It's a problem with Catalina..